# filter using lambda function and zip

Tags: python, lambda, filter, zip

I am trying to check if the list is empty return the related description using filter with lambda function and zip.

its working but the result is not as expected.

```
list_of_lists = [ [ ] , [ 'not_empty' ] ]
list_of_desc = [ 'first_list_is_empty' , 'second_list_not_empty' ]

result = list(filter(lambda item : item[1] if not item[0] else '',zip(list_of_lists,list_of_desc )))

result
Out[180]: [([], 'first_list_is_empty')]
```

Dont understand why its returning the tuple, i was expecting 'first_list_is_empty' as i'm slicing the tuple.

Comment: `help(filter)` -> "Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which function(item)  is true." Your lambda returns True for the first element of the iterator so that element is returned from the filter.

Comment: Spot on thanks @mechanical_meat

Answer (score 0):

This is because filter() does not modify what is returned, it only uses the lambda to determine if it "should" return the tuple. To be clear:

```
func = lambda item : item[1] if not item[0] else ''
func = lambda item : bool(item[1] if not item[0] else '')
```

Are the exact same filtering function.

To modify what is returned, use the builtin map() function instead. Also note that filter() defaults to removing False things automatically, you don't need a lambda.

```
func   = lambda item : item[1] if not item[0] else ''
result = list(filter(None,map(func,zip(list_of_lists,list_of_desc))))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works @Bobby Ocean.Trying to get my head around as None is not callable() how its working as callable function in the filter .i'm using bool to be more explicit. list (filter ( bool , map( lambda item: item [ 1 ] if not item[ 0 ] else '  ',zip (list_of_lists,list_of_desc))))

Comment: Well, None just means to choose the default, it doesn't actually use None itself. If it is passed a None, it defaults to the function "lambda item : bool(item)". Yes, putting "bool" is equivalent. I only put None because that is what the help says, run "filter?" in an ipython session.